# ImportError with flask+gunicorn+supervisord after logging out ssh

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn, supervisord

Greetings and salutations,

I'm trying to get my Flask app running on my Ubuntu VPS with gunicorn+nginx and supervisor. When I log in to my vps through ssh, everything works. When I log out, I get a bad gateway.

The gunicorn error log gives me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/michael/dev/myapp/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 131, in handle_request
File "/home/michael/dev/myapp/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
File "/home/michael/dev/myapp/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/contrib/fixers.py", line 144, in __call__
File "/home/michael/dev/myapp/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
File "/home/michael/dev/myapp/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1407, in handle_exception
File "/home/michael/dev/myapp/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1420, in log_exception
File "/home/michael/dev/myapp/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 582, in logger
ImportError: No module named logging
```

Which seems really weird to me. Flask uses python's own logging module. I can import the module in the python shell. I also run everything in a virtualenv.

For reference, my supervisor.conf:

```
[program:gunicorn] 
directory = /home/michael/dev/myapp
user=michael
command = /home/michael/dev/myapp/env/bin/gunicorn mpn:app
directory = /home/michael/dev/myapp
environment=PATH="/home/michael/dev/myapp/env/bin"
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=True
stdout_logfile = /home/michael/dev/myapp/logs/supervisor.log
stderr_logfile = /home/michael/dev/myapp/logs/supervisor_error.log
```

I hope someone can help me. I've spent way too many hours stackover-google-maillist-ing this.

**Edit:**

I switched to Debian and this problem doesn't occur anymore, though I'm still curious to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

That would seem to indicate that your python installation is broken. This can happen if you haven't set up some dependencies of python before you install it. For example, failing to install gcc can cause python to fail to compile some libraries. Try re-installing python and setting up a new virtualenv, and testing if you can import logging when in that virtualenv.

I also suggest you use [virtualenvwrapper](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) instead of virtualenv on its own; it makes virtual environments a lot easier to work with. When you tested importing logging in the python shell, did you run source bin/activate first to ensure you were testing in your virtual environment? Finally, do your supervisor logs contain any errors?

Comment: That'd seem kinda funky, since it's a rather fresh Ubuntu install (12.04LTS) which came with python et al. I'll give it a shot though (but I feel like I'll break more than I'll fix). And yes, I did test inside my virtual environment. Supervisor logs contain nothing of note.